# Issue with dynamically generated javascript link with PHP

Tags: php

```
<a href="javascript:exampleFunction(<?php echo $val;?>)">example link</a>
```

returns PHP error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';'

Any ideas? (Hope this question makes sense. I'm trying to fix someone else's code.)

Comment: Is there any other code on this page?

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: whats $val in your code?

Comment: What is the output of $val ? Have you tried wrapping <?php echo $val;?> with single quotes ? eg : <a href="javascript:exampleFunction('<?php echo $val;?>')">example link</a>

Comment: What they are trying to say, is that there is no error in that line, nor is there an object operator

Comment: fwiw, there's nothing wrong with the code presented, see this simple test: http://ideone.com/TheUJ

Comment: Please provide more code, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Martin - That's a PHP error, not a Javascript as you suggest. The <?php ?> take care of the quoted string issue (and in this case, there isn't any).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry about that guys, the problem was `<?php echo val;?>` instead of `<?php echo $val;?>`. Sometimes the eyes betray the mind...

Comment: I'm sorry~~~ *in a little mouse voice, looking down at my toes* :P

Answer (score 0):

Check that there's not a "`<?`" or "`<?php`" at the beginning of the file. This code assumes you're not already within a PHP block. If you are, then you'll have to adjust (remove it). Or, you'll need to add close `?>` somewhere before this html, and a `<?php` after it...

Comment: double fail, if he had an unclosed php tag he would get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' `

Comment: when some one posts a half baked question, don't post a half baked answer. Ask them for more information instead.

Comment: [previous comments redacted] Note that this would only be an issue outside the scope of the sample code provided. But, it is a common problem when debugging a file. Something else to check and keep in the toolbox.